# Access SQL query for sorting

Tags: ms-access

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iR85.jpg) - Relationships

Find employees who took some kind of management class (i.e., a class whose name ends with management). List employees’ last and first name, class name, and the class date. Sort the query output by last name in ascending.

I did the following, But the query is not working. Cannot find the ClassName that ends with management.

```
SELECT E.Last, E.First, C.ClassName, C.Date
FROM EMPLOYEES AS E, EMPLOYEE_TRAINING AS ET, CLASSES AS C
WHERE E.EmployeeID = ET.EmployeeID AND C.ClassID = ET.ClassID AND C.ClassName LIKE "Management*"
ORDER BY E.Last ASC;
```

Comment: question - output by last name in ascending - query - ORDER BY E.Last DESC; spot the difference

Answer (score 0):

Replace "Management*" with "*Management" or "%Management" because you want to find ClassName that ends with Management, not start with Management